# Running an EE site on IIS. What are the "gotchas"?

Tags: server, windows, iis

I may be taking on a project for a large EE site that would most likely be running on IIS. Although I have some very minor experience of IIS I have never run PHP on it let alone an EE site. I don't envisage problems with getting things sorted on the server since the company I will be working with are an IT firm.

Are there any specific things I should be looking out for with regards to running an ExpressionEngine site in this environment?

Answer (score 3):

If at all possible try to convince the client to let you run WAMP. I had to manage an IIS EE site for 3 years and it was an absolute nightmare.

1. Make sure you have .php [set as a default document](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753615%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) and higher priority than .html.
2. You may want to purchase [ISAPI_Rewrite](http://www.isapirewrite.com/), which would allow you to use an .htaccess for any URL rewriting.
3. Permissions are a nightmare. You have to use the Windows Explorer "permissions" interface to set upload directories and whatnot.

The biggest recommendation I have is reading through [Microsoft's guide](http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/expressionengine-on-iis). Let us know if you run into anything crazy and I, for one, am happy to help.